# How to add custom link in Collection Grid in Magento2?

Tags: php, magento, collections, grid, magento2

I have create a grid and I want to add a link in this grid in Magento2 eg:View,Add link on order id etc.

Controller : **Inchoo/Helloworld/Controller/Index/Index.php**

Model      : **Inchoo/Helloworld/Model/Orderprocessing.php**

ResourceModel : **Inchoo/Helloworld/Model/ResourceModel/Orderprocessing.php**

Collection : **Inchoo/Helloworld/Model/ResourceModel/Orderprocessing/Collection.php**

Layout : **Inchoo/Helloworld/view/adminhtml/layout/helloworld_orderprocessing_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <!--<uiComponent name="inchoo_orderprocessing_grid"/>-->
            <block class="Inchoo\Helloworld\Block\Adminhtml\Orderprocessing" name="inchoo_orderprocessing_grid">
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid" name="inchoo_orderprocessing_grid.grid" as="grid">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">orderprocessing_id</argument>
                        <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">Inchoo\Helloworld\Model\ResourceModel\Orderprocessing\Collection</argument>
                        <argument name="default_sort" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
                        <argument name="default_dir" xsi:type="string">ASC</argument>
                        <argument name="save_parameters_in_session" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\ColumnSet" name="inchoo_orderprocessing_grid.grid.columnSet" as="grid.columnSet">
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="increment_id">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order id</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">increment_id</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
                                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="shipment_id">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipment id</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">shipment_id</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
                                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="tracking_number">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tracking Number</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">tracking_number</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
                                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="created_at">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created Time</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">created_at</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">date</argument>
                                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mean custom grid action? Check this http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-backend-add-custom-grid-action-target-_self-or-_blank

by the way do you have any idea to add tracking number to sales order grid ?